# Sequelize many to many relation are not saving in database as foreign keys

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, schema

I have two tables `campaign` and `audience` , and I am setting many-to-many relationship between them.
Campaign schema,

```
const Campaign = sequelize.define("campaign", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  campaign_name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  text: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  start_date: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  end_date: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
```

Audience Schema,

```
const Audience = sequelize.define("audience", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  audience_name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    allowNull: false,
  },
  phone: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(12),
    allowNull: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
    allowNull: true,
  },
});
```

Then I declared many-to-many table campaign_audience,

```
const CampaignAudience = sequelize.define("campaign_audience", {
  audienceId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: Audience,
      key: "id",
    },
  },
  campaignId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {
      model: Campaign,
      key: "id",
    },
  },
});
```

Then set relations between them,

```
CampaignModel.belongsToMany(AudienceModel, {
  through: CampaignAudienceModel,
});
AudienceModel.belongsToMany(CampaignModel, {
  through: CampaignAudienceModel,
});
```

Now I have all tables created. Issue is `campaignId`, `audienceId` in `campaign_audience` table ain't foreign keys. Say I have campaign whose id 1, and audience whose id 11,12. I can post audience with id 43 and that saves in table which is not a valid audience id. How to set junction table ids as foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, if I don't declare campaign_audience schema manullay, in auto generated field id's set as foreign keys.